# Chrome 31 does not call FB.getLoginStatus on back button click

Tags: google-chrome, facebook-javascript-sdk, browser-cache

I am using facebook's javascript SDK in one of my web app.
I use FB.init to initiate the fb object and FB.getLoginStatus to check user's status.
Everything works fine when load the page.
But when i click some link inside my page and then try to go back to my last page by clicking back button of browser FB.getLoginStatus is not calling the callback.
This problem occurs only in Chrome's new version 31. In all other browsers it works fine.
Anybody come across this problem?

Answer (score 3):

It is a Facebook javascript SDK bug happening on Chrome 31 only. They are still investigating.
You will get more details on Facebook bug platform : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/391240127674701/

Comment: It is generally a good idea to extract the most pertinent information from the link in order to ensure the answer does not rot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it.. i had the same problem, and turns out i had a facebook extension that was messing with facebook calls once you hit the back button. Once i removed it, it all worked fine.

Correction: the Web Security Keeper 1.0.0 extension caused it.

Comment: please tell which extension did you have, so others could remove it too.

Comment: Wich exact extension?. Thanks!

Comment: sorry my mistake it was Web Security Keeper 1.0.0 extension, i removed this one and also the facebook one but after a check it was the security one that caused it.

Comment: I don't have these extensions in my chrome. But it still happens.
I have chrome 32.

Comment: I also have chrome 32, i would advise you to check all your extensions and see if one is causing the issue..

Answer (score 0):

this is possible caused when you trying todo facebook javascript sdk with jQuery.
try using plain javascript init from there https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart